# R - Update column values by list

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset of demographic counts and I'm in the process of normalizing groupings of similar columns.

For example, I have defined

```
gender <- c("male","female") 
income <- c("income_0_50k","income_50k_100k","income_over_100k")
```

To normalize, using gender as an example, my plan was to divide male by the sum of male + female, update the male column with the new values, then do the same calculation for female. I made a function that would accept any one of these groupings and perform that calculation, but it is not working as intended. Here is my code:

```
percent.total <- function(df,x){ 
  tot <- rowSums(df[x])
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    df[x[i]] <- df[x[i]]/tot
  }
}

percent.total(dat,gender)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(df[x[i]], df[x]) :
‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

When the code is tested outside of the function and for loop, it performs as intended when i <- 1, but not i <- 2:

```
i <- 1
tot <- rowSums(dat[gender])
dat[gender[i]] <- dat[gender[i]]/tot
```

There are several column groupings that need the same operation performed upon them, so I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
male    female
1,487   1,501
726     810
632     615
655     692
616     599
1,945   1,544
888     980
```

Here's what the output should look like:

```
    male    female
0.497657296 0.502342704
0.47265625  0.52734375
0.506816359 0.493183641
0.486265776 0.513734224
0.506995885 0.493004115
0.557466323 0.442533677
0.475374732 0.524625268
```

Thanks

Comment: `data.frame(lapply(df[, gender], "/", e2 = rowSums(df[, gender])))`

Comment: or mutate(df, across(everything(), ~ .x / rowSums(df)))

Comment: @Roland Apologies for the delay in response. Your solution works for the gender grouping. How could you succinctly apply the same steps to both demographic groupings individually c(gender, income) (without grouping gender and income in rowSums)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are calculating `tot` again the second time around, when the totals haven't changed. In other words, for the second time around, the first row is:

```
       male female
1 0.4976573   1501
```

So when you find the sum of that row again, it's not 2988 as before, but 1501.4976573.

There are lots of ways of fixing this. Here are a couple:

```
# adapting your code:
percent.total <- function(df,col, total){ 
  for(i in seq_along(df[col])){
    df[x[i]] <- df[x[i]]/total
  }
}
tot <- rowSums(dat[gender])
i <- 1
dat[gender[i]] = percent.total(dat, gender[i], tot)
i <- 2
dat[gender[i]] = percent.total(dat, gender[i], tot)
```

How I would do it:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(dat, across(any_of(gender), ~ . / rowSums(dat)))
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response. Your solution is close, but dat has more columns than male/female, so your code would work if you changed it to

mutate(dat, across(any_of(gender), ~ . / rowSums(dat[,gender)))

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(sum=rowSums(across(c(male,female))),
             male=male/sum,
             female=female/sum
             )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 7 × 3
   male female   sum
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.498  0.502  2988
2 0.473  0.527  1536
3 0.507  0.493  1247
4 0.486  0.514  1347
5 0.507  0.493  1215
6 0.557  0.443  3489
7 0.475  0.525  1868
```